# Although the text is present in the pagesource() when I execute pageSource().contains.(text), it returns false

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find the subheading text: "You can join this team without approval if you have a farzanshaikh.com email address."
Although this text is present in the page source, it always returns false for .contains()

Code:

```
package JUnitTesting;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestOne {
    WebDriver driver;
    String BaseUrl;
    String TeamDomain = "farzanshaikh.com";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        BaseUrl = "http://farzanshaikh.flock.co/";
        driver.get(BaseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String element = driver.getPageSource();
        System.out.println(element);

        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("You can join this team without approval if you have a "+TeamDomain+" email address.")){
            System.out.println("The Sub Heading on the Team URL page is Correct");
        }
        else{
            System.err.println("The Sub Heading on the Team URL page is Wrong.");
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.quit();
    }


}
```

Comment: There has to be a difference if "contains" returns false. Can you do a `System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());` and post the interesting part of it? Maybe you are overlooking something.

Comment: <p class="team-canjoin-domains">You can join this team without approval if you have a <span class="domains-list"><span class="highlight">farzanshaikh.com</span></span> email address.</p>

Comment: Why are you searching the said text from pagesource you can directly search the element text from `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#step-2-block > p.team-canjoin-domains")).getText();`

Comment: @kushal. i basically wanted to compare if the text present is same as the one i want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't see any issue either in your code or in the result.

Manually when we look into the webpage we can see the text `You can join this team without approval if you have a farzanshaikh.com email address.`

But when we try to get the pagesource the part of the string cotaining the text reads like: `You can join this team without approval if you have a <span class='domains-list'>{{canJoinDomains}}</span> email address.`

Finally, you are trying to use `contains` to validate if the first string is present in the second string. Hence it fails. If you can reduce the first string to something like `You can join this team without approval`, it would return True.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Works by just entering "You can join this team without approval"
but is there any other way to check for the complete string "You can join this team without approval if you have a farzanshaikh.com email address."

Comment: @ShaikhFarzan Yes you can do that even. To do that, you need to search the entire text `You can join this team without approval if you have a <span class='domains-list'>{{canJoinDomains}}</span> email address.` in the pagesource.